# No cargan los scripts desde el BundleConfig.cs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy empezando un proyecto en ASP .NET MVC 5 en Visual Studio 2017, he creado mi archivo de **BundleConfig.cs** con la siguiente información:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;
namespace Login
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            // jQuery
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"));
            // CSS
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                      "~/Content/animate.css",
                      "~/Content/style.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

tengo en mi **_LayoutPage.cshtml** lo siguiente en el encabezado:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/font-awesome/css")
</head>
```

y al cargar mi pagina aparece sin estilos, si reviso la consola(F12) del navegador me aparecen las rutas que no se encontraron con un error 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparece sin estilos debido a que no se leído la configuración de los **Bundles**, en el archivo **Global.asax.cs** hay que agregar:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

quedando de esta manera el archivo:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
namespace Login
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

> **NOTA:** hay que tener en cuenta que se tiene que agregar la referencia de `System.Web.Optimization;`

Por otro lado también hay que verificar que en el **web.config**  de las vistas exista en `namespaces` el nombre de `System.Web.Optimization` de lo contrario hay que agregarlo quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
<namespaces>
  <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  <add namespace="Login" />
</namespaces>
```

Answer (score 1):

En lo siguiente `~/Content/cssdesign` es mi contenido a cargarse con el bundle (digamos) personalizado bajo esa etiqueta. Igual puede añadirlo a los ya existentes y no tener que crear uno nuevo.

Realiza lo siguiente; en la página del Layout correspondiente el `@Styles.Render("~/Content/cssdesign")`; y en el `BundleConfigs.cs`

```
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssdesign").Include(
              /* otras referencias CSS */
              "~/Content/font-awesome.css"));
```

Añadiendolo como se muestra a continuación:

```
// Omito lo anterior

    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        // jQuery
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"));
        // CSS
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                  "~/Content/animate.css",
                  "~/Content/style.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssdesign").Include(
                  /* otras referencias CSS */
                  "~/Content/font-awesome.css"));
    }
// Omito lo que posterior
```

**Nota:** Si es CSS en el `BundleConfig` usa **`StyleBundle`**, si es JavaScript **`ScriptBundle`**; si por error usas al revés marcara errores al momento de cargar la página.
No he movido más y funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que tangas configurado un bundle para '~/font-awesome/css'.

El parámetro del constructor de ScriptBundle indica como se llamará tu bundle, y es usado para referirse a este.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/[nombre_del_bundle]").Include(
            "[archivos_que_contiene_el_bundle1]"));
```

Y te refieres a el como:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/[nombre_del_bundle]")
```